# Tab bar gets covered by the new view

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have built an app based on a tab bar controller. While I am on one of the tab views I want to be able to swipe my finger and switch to another tab view of which the index on the tabBarController in unknown. I am therefore calling the desired viewcontroller from its nib. The view gets swapped correctly but the problem is that it appears ABOVE the tab bar itself, covering it completely and making it become unusable! How can I push the view back or the tab bar up? Thanks

```
- (IBAction)swipeLeftDetected:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
DesiredViewController *controllerInstance =[[DesiredViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DesiredViewController" bundle:nil];
controllerInstance.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:controllerInstance animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: First, presentModalViewController:animated: is deprecated in iOS6.

Comment: Second, it's supposed behaviour: On iPhone and iPod touch devices, the view of modalViewController is always presented full screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`presentModalViewController:animated` always uses whole screen: On iPhone and iPod touch devices, the view of modalViewController is always presented full screen. On iPad, the presentation depends on the value in the modalPresentationStyle property.

If you really use UITabBarController, it instantiates view controllers of its tabs. So trying to instantiate view controller of one of tabs manually is wrong. You will end in a mess of view controllers instances.

Set property `selectedIndex` of your UITabBarController to switch tab. I think you need this. But it will be switched without animation.

If you know only pointer of controller you want to switch to, ask `viewControllers` property about controller's index and than switch tab by its index:

```
self.selectedIndex = [[self viewControllers] indexOfObject:viewController];
```

Comment: Mmmmm.... Using the indexes would be really inconvenient in my case as from the same project I develop several different targets. But mostly it is a pity not being able to use the nice animations of presentModalViewController:animated. Are we sure there is now way to get around this? It seems crazy. Is any animation possible at all if I load the view by its index using [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:index]?

Comment: UITabViewController just switches tabs. Without any animation. If you need some animation, afraid, it woun't be UITabViewConroller.

Comment: By the way, you say it's inconvenient in your case to use indexes of tabs. You should read UITabBarController documentation. viewControllers property holds array of view controllers. If you know pointer of view controller, you could switch to appropriate tab with call self.selectedIndex = [[self viewControllers] indexOfObject:viewController];